# Reduce the size of the People Picker column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, people-picker

hope you're doing well.

I'm on SharePoint online and looking for a solution to reduce the number of visible users in a People Picker column.

I mean, if you create a "multiline of text", you'll see that if you start writing enough in the column, SharePoint Online will give you a preview of the first few lines and hide the rest of the content.

I'm trying to find out if there is a possibility to have a people picker doing the same. I have a list with a people picker field enabled for multiple users. one item has 20 users, the other one has 50 users so that makes the list being very long only because of this. I'd like to find a way for SharePoint  to show only the first 5 users.

Hope some can help me on this.

Thanks a lot in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no OOB way to meet yout requirement.

As a workaround, we could use column formatting to judge characters exceed to determine if all the people will be shown.

If the selected people exceeds 30 characters, show "More than 5 users", if not, show the selected users.

After doing this, if you want to see all users, you need to select the item then check all users.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(@currentField.title +'^','^')>=30,'More than 5 users','@currentField.title')"
}
```

My test result for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Julie_MSFT, thanks a lot for your answer. that's sooo cool !!! waw... but i don't have the same as you show. I have an item with 3 people, another with 5 people, another with 30 people ... and all are showing the message "More than 5 users" . would you have any idea how to fix this ? I tried to adapt the number in your code but that doesn't help> thanks

Comment: AAAHHH OK !!! i understand , it counts the number of characters !!! It works then ... Cool, thanks a lot  !! :-)